# extract value from the last row in table in shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, perl

I have a file (data.txt) with below content. It has multiple rows in it separated by sequence of `-`. It looks like a graphical table put in a file. In the below file, first row has all the column names and all other rows are the actual data for all those columns.

```
Connecting to the ControlService endpoint

Found 3 rows.
Requests List:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Client ID                                                                   | Client Type                  | Service Type | Status               | Trust Domain              | Data Instance Name | Data Version | Creation Time              | Last Update                | Scheduled Time | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 REFRESH_ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS_1465901168866                              | ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS | SYSTEM       | COMPLETED            | RRA Bulk Client    | soa_server1       | 18.2.2.0.0  | 2016-06-14 03:49:55 -07:00 | 2016-06-14 03:49:57 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 500333443                                                          | CREATE                        | [FA_GSI]     | COMPLETED            | holder       | soa_server1       | 18.3.2.0.0  | 2018-08-07 11:59:57 -07:00 | 2018-08-07 12:04:37 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 500333446                                                          | CREATE                        | [FA_GSI]     | COMPLETED            | holder-test  | soa_server1       | 18.3.2.0.0  | 2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00 | 2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to parse the above file and extract value from the last row. I want to extract value of "Client ID" and "Trust Domain" column in the last row which is:

```
Client ID: 500333446
Trust Domain: holder-test
```

Is this possible to do in shell script or perl or python?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do in python. I suggest csv module and customize delimiter to '|'.

Comment: If the issue is resolved please mark one of the answers as correct

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @paragbaxi is fine I would only add an condition to filter out the lines containing only "------". Like so:

```
import csv

lines_to_skip = 4
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for i in range(lines_to_skip):
        next(reader) #Skipping lines

    data = []
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].find("---") != 0:  #Check what position has symbol "---" if 0 then skip
            print(line)
            data.append(line)


print("Last row:\n{}".format(data[-1]))
print("Client ID:{} Domain:{}".format(data[-1][0].replace(" ",""),data[-1][4].replace(" ","")))  #replace() just removes unnecessary spaces
```

Output:

```
[' Client ID                                                                   ', ' Client Type                  ', ' Service Type ', ' Status               ', ' Trust Domain              ', ' Data Instance Name ', ' Data Version ', ' Creation Time              ', ' Last Update                ', ' Scheduled Time ', ' ']
[' REFRESH_ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS_1465901168866                              ', ' ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS ', ' SYSTEM       ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' RRA Bulk Client    ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.2.2.0.0  ', ' 2016-06-14 03:49:55 -07:00 ', ' 2016-06-14 03:49:57 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
[' 500333443                                                          ', ' CREATE                        ', ' [FA_GSI]     ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' holder       ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.3.2.0.0  ', ' 2018-08-07 11:59:57 -07:00 ', ' 2018-08-07 12:04:37 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
[' 500333446                                                          ', ' CREATE                        ', ' [FA_GSI]     ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' holder-test  ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.3.2.0.0  ', ' 2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00 ', ' 2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
Last row:
[' 500333446                                                          ', ' CREATE                        ', ' [FA_GSI]     ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' holder-test  ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.3.2.0.0  ', ' 2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00 ', ' 2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
Client ID:500333446 Domain:holder-test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: yeah this make sense as I can see what's the last row. now how can I extract value of `Client ID` and `Trust Domain` from last row? Basically it should give me these `500333446` and `holder-test`

Comment: @flash Yes, check my edited answer, this fragment `.replace(" ","")` replaces spaces so data looks more compacted you could also just use a substring to remove them

Comment: yeah this works fine.. thanks for the help.. also if I just need to print domain value without any of its key then will it be like this `print("".format(data[-1][4].replace(" ","")))`. I tried this and it prints nothing. Basically I just want to print `holder-test` that's all.

Comment: You are using print incorrectly it should be like so `print("{}".format(data[-1][4].replace(" ","")))` the `{}` is a placeholder for where to inject the value in a string

Comment: yeah I fixed it after checking that out again.

Comment: hey if my `data.csv` file has some new lines at the end then in that case script is failing so I decided to add this if check - `if line[0].find("---") != 0 and line[0].strip():` but still it doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong in my if check? That's the line I see at the end `[' \t\t']`

Comment: @flash Well those extra lines are not empty they have content `[' \t\t']` tabs in your case, if they were truly empty changing the condition to this `if line and line[0].find("---") != 0: ` would suffice. If this is the case you would like to handle that is lines with only spaces or tabs that appear to be empty the code should rewritten using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do in python. I suggest csv module and customize delimiter to '|'.

```
import csv
with open('s', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
  for row in reader:
      print(row)
```

Gives the following list:

```
['Connecting to the ControlService endpoint']
[]
['Found 3 rows.']
['Requests List:']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
[' Client ID                                                                   ', ' Client Type                  ', ' Service Type ', ' Status               ', ' Trust Domain              ', ' Data Instance Name ', ' Data Version ', ' Creation Time              ', ' Last Update                ', ' Scheduled Time ', ' ']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
[' REFRESH_ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS_1465901168866                              ', ' ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS ', ' SYSTEM       ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' RRA Bulk Client    ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.2.2.0.0  ', ' 2016-06-14 03:49:55 -07:00 ', ' 2016-06-14 03:49:57 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
[' 500333443                                                          ', ' CREATE                        ', ' [FA_GSI]     ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' holder       ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.3.2.0.0  ', ' 2018-08-07 11:59:57 -07:00 ', ' 2018-08-07 12:04:37 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
[' 500333446                                                          ', ' CREATE                        ', ' [FA_GSI]     ', ' COMPLETED            ', ' holder-test  ', ' soa_server1       ', ' 18.3.2.0.0  ', ' 2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00 ', ' 2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00 ', ' ---            ', ' ']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
```

You could easily skip the first 4 rows in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import csv
... from itertools import islice
... 
... with open('infile', 'r') as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(islice(f, 5, None, 2), delimiter='|')
...     result = [
...         {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in line.items()} for line in reader
...     ]
... 
>>> last_row = result[-1]
>>> import json; print(json.dumps(last_row, indent=2))
{
  "Client ID": "500333446",
  "Client Type": "CREATE",
  "Service Type": "[FA_GSI]",
  "Status": "COMPLETED",
  "Trust Domain": "holder-test",
  "Data Instance Name": "soa_server1",
  "Data Version": "18.3.2.0.0",
  "Creation Time": "2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00",
  "Last Update": "2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00",
  "Scheduled Time": "---",
  "": ""
}
>>> last_row['Client ID']
'500333446'
>>> last_row['Trust Domain']
'holder-test'
```

Answer (score 0):

One in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}!/^-+/{c=$1;t=$5}END{print "Client ID:" c ORS "Trust Domain:" t}' file
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="|" }                                # pipe-separator
!/^-+/ {                                        # process if doesnt start with dashes
    c=$1                                        # client value
    t=$5                                        # trust domain value
}
END {                                           # in the end
    print "Client ID:" c ORS "Trust Domain:" t  # output the last value pair
}' file
```

Output:

```
Client ID: 500333446                                                          
Trust Domain: holder-test
```